# How to add a script attribute to addItem

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, external

I want to add an embedded MailChimp script to my Magento 1 installation. However, the script has an attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
```

(the data-dojo-config attribute)

How can I add this attribute using the addItem method?

Comment: Do you **need** to do this in xml? You could add it in miscellaneous scripts or miscellaneous html (system>config>general>design)

Comment: @jscar It would make my life alot easier if I could add in the layout :p Then I can just move it to another environment without importing the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find was this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <reference name="head">

            <!-- Embedded JS for MailChimp Subscribe popup -->

            <block type="core/text" name="mailchimp.popup.embed">
                <action method="setText">
                    <text>
                        <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>]]>
                    </text>
                </action>
            </block>

        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```